# Carriage return CNC G code

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator, g-code

I'm writing a plugin that exports Gcode form illustrator in javascript. Everything works, except when I load the gcode onto the CNC software, none of the text appears because it's in the wrong format. When I open it in a text editor, it all appears on one line. When I open it in an notepad++, all of the carriage returns are there and look just fine. I'm using \r\n as a carriage return and I've tried \n\r and it still appears the same. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm writing the plugin on mac, and transferring to PC where the CNC software is. The carriage returns shouldn't, but do work on my mac.

Here is a sample:

docText += "G90"+ '\r\n';

Comment: Did you ever complete this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the G-Code software does it's own line ending translation. You probably have the setting wrong there, and it doesn't matter so much what line endings you start with.

What software are you using?